# Lenovo ThinkPad x250 wont charge when On. Installing Windows fixes this

Tags: thinkpad, charger

I have a Problem with my ThinkPad and Linux. Debian Jessy to be exact. I am using all the original parts Lenovo provided me with. After approximately 8 months now my notebook refused to charge when turned on. After much debate with the Lenovo customer "service" in which they were unable to help me and refused any help within the warranty, I installed Windows in hope that their diagnostic tool will show me something. However I did not wait for that because somehow just by installing Windows the problem got solved by itself and I reinstalled my Debian Drive. Since today the problem is back. Any ideas what to make of this?
An "installation" with a generalized Windows 10 image did not work. Only a complete reinstall of Windows seems to do the trick.

Comment: Does it not charge at all? Lenovo has a energy feature or power manager driver that can help protect the life of your battery. I'm not 100% how the feature works, but it does something that limits the charging of the battery.

Comment: Well it does charge. But only when turned of. The second i turn it on, it stops charging.

Comment: Does it stop charging, but maintain the battery level? Or does it just drain the battery as if no charger was connected? Does linux detect that you are plugged in, or does it say nothing?

Comment: It drains the battery and debian acts as if there is no charger present

Comment: The ThinkPads have some configuration to regulate in which cases the power is used to recharge the battery, but at least until few years ago they were editable only in Windows. Nowadays check https://askubuntu.com/a/72570 http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html